# Sending email through GMail SMTP server sending copy to sending address inbox

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

We have a web application that is sending emails on behalf of one of our clients and using their Gsuite SMTP account. They are complaining that they are getting copies of every email our app is sending in their Inbox of this sending account in the Gmail web client, but I don't see anywhere that our app is including the sending email address as a CC or BCC. We do set the reply-to as the sending address of course.

Here is the headers of an example that showed up in their sending account inbox. The VM-App-DB is our web app. I believe a CC would show if we were CC'ing. Not sure though if there would be any indication if we were BCC'ing in these headers? Any other ideas?

```
Return-Path: <info@mysite.com>
Received: from VM-App-DB ([52.161.999.999])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id y19sm1186470ili.47.2020.09.01.14.48.1111
        for <john_doe@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 01 Sep 2020 14:48:17 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <5f4ec1a1.1c69fb81.828e2.444c@mx.google.com>
Date: Tue, 01 Sep 2020 14:48:17 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Original-Date: 1 Sep 2020 15:48:17 -0600
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "My Site" <info@mysite.com>
To: john_doe@gmail.com
Reply-To: "My Site" <info@mysite.com>
Subject: test   
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Answer (score 0):

You send an email via Gmail SMTP using another email-client (your webapp). This creates the mail in the sent-mail box in the Gmail account. Like with the webmail Gmail-client, each outgoing mail is kept in Gmail.

Using Thunderbird or Outlook to read all mail in a Gmail account, you get all sent mail as well. This is in fact handy, as it's an archive and proof of what you did. If the complaining organisation doesn't want to see all these mails, here are some tips:

1. You make a rule in Gmail to delete these outgoing mails. I think this is a bad idea, but it's an option.
2. You make a rule in Outlook/Thunderbird to archive these mails when they are downloaded. They don't show in the inbox, but they are saved in the archive and can be found later.
3. You can setup a rule in Gmail to archive all these mails automatically. This is not an error in your code.

From your reply:

> And to compound the issue, they have forwarding on to send any inbox email to a third party help ticket system. So all these emails are turning into frivolous new tickets.

This sounds more and more like a classic XY problem. You're asking a question about the solution you thought about, a solution that is not working, but the solution is probably not the proper way to handle this.

Does this organisation handle all their mail via gmail? Do they have a domain name linked to that, so their address is not @gmail.com?

Some suggestions:

- You can send those webapp mails out via another gmail address, one that doesn't forward all mail into that ticket system.
- You should remove the default forwarding "everything" rule, and set a new rule that excludes the webapp mails.
- The ticket system probably does have all kind of inboxes. Use one specifically for the webapp mails.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. They are just using the Gmail web app as their email client. They are ok with seeing the sent emails in their Sent mail folder, but the problem is it is showing up in their Inbox in gmail. And to compound the issue, they have forwarding on to send any inbox email to a third party help ticket system. So all these emails are turning into frivolous new tickets.

Comment: You leave out of lot of useful information in your question. Please update it and explain everything about the setup and what you tried. Now you're leaving me guessing things, and that is a waste of time. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this reply is a bit late but the OP's issue is likely due to a "filter" being configured within the Gmail account (settings/gear icon). I found out the hard way that if the FROM (email address) in a SMTP-sent email is also listed in Gmail's filter it puts a copy of the SMTP-sent email in folders SENT and INBOX!